# Removing unwanted newline characters when adding <p> in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, newline, wysiwyg

When loading content with a set of paragraphs in CKEditor, it replaces my `<p>` tags with `<p>&#x9;`

That means the editor converts this:

```
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

into what ends up like this:

```
<p>
   paragraph 1</p>
<p>
   paragraph 2</p>
<p>
   paragraph 3</p>
```

How do I fix it so that CKEditor doesn't add the extra newline characters when it sees the paragraph tags?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this line to the ckeditor.js configuration file:

```
n.setRules('p',{indent:false,breakAfterOpen:false});
```

More about the formatting of the HTML Writer can be found in [Developers Guide: Output Formatting](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting) at CKSource Docs.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It's been one of those things about the CKEditor that has annoyed me so much and I never knew how to change it. I have no clue who would want a newline and indent inside a p tag :)

Answer (score 29):

Elsewhere (my apologies that I did not make a note of where I got it from.), I found code to fix this problem for all the block-level tags. For my project, the extra new-lines were a problem due to outputting to XML and importing into other applications as CDATA.

So, in my ckeditor_config.js file, after the CKEDITOR.editorConfig function, I put in this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( ev ) {
  var blockTags = ['div','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','p','pre','li','blockquote','ul','ol',
  'table','thead','tbody','tfoot','td','th',];

  for (var i = 0; i < blockTags.length; i++)
  {
     ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( blockTags[i], {
        indent : false,
        breakBeforeOpen : true,
        breakAfterOpen : false,
        breakBeforeClose : false,
        breakAfterClose : true
     });
  }
});
```

Some of those elements may not need this treatment; obviously the blockTags array can easily be edited to your needs.

Comment: Looks like this answer is continuing to help 4 years later. Maintaining an old system and needed this to solve an issue with tags ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a setting to format the code, or auto-indent or something along those lines.  It was intended to make the source code more readable.  It's effectiveness is open to opinion I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and would like to do it at instance level and don't want to touch the configuration files so that it is easy to update/upgrade.  Then here is another solution.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    on :
    {
        instanceReady : function( ev )
        {
            // Output paragraphs as <p>Text</p>.
            this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
                {
                    indent : false,
                    breakBeforeOpen : true,
                    breakAfterOpen : false,
                    breakBeforeClose : false,
                    breakAfterClose : true
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Reference: [Output Formatting](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution that would work like a charm:

edit **contents.css** file and setting style for paragraphs e.g.

```
 p {
     margin-top:0px;
     margin-bottom:5px;
 }
```