# CKEditor insert blank P tags instead of not valid elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

Press Source button, then past this text to editor:

```
<p><h2>
    Info:</h2>
<p>
    <dt>
        Controls</dt>
</p>
```

After that press Source to switch to view mode. After that again press Source to see code.
This HTML converted to:

```
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<h2>
    Info:</h2>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<dl>
    <dt>
        Controls</dt>
</dl>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<ul>
    <li>
        GK Volume, Down/S1 Switch, Up/S2 Switch, Select Switch</li>
</ul>
```

How to configure CKEditor do not insert this block:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: You can't have a `<h2>` inside a `<p>`, if that's what you're asking. Otherwise, why do you paste the `<p>` if you don't want it in the resulting document?

Comment: Well, the best possible solution would be not use a WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Truth but then he would be left with invalid HTML!

Comment: @MrLister: In which case he should not write invalid HTML! No program can ever EVER 100% accurately correct invalid HTML, nor would anyone be stupid enough to try and write one. Write valid HTML yourself, and don't use a WYSIWYG. As simple as that.

Comment: @Truth an editor can be very educational for beginners, especially as it shows you what you should have written in the first place, when switching between source and WYSIWYG mode. Of course no editor gets it right all the time, but at least if it mangles your input, you'll know you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547090/ckeditor-adds-unwanted-newline-to-p

Answer (score 1):

The editor does what it thinks is best.
Since empty paragraphs are supposed to collapse to zero height, according to the official recommendations, it puts a nbsp in to keep it from being empty. And it tries to create valid HTML from your input, that's also the reason it inserts the `<dl>` and `</dl>` tags.