# CKEditor inserts \n automatically

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

My problem is with `CKEditor`, it adds `\n` when I submit data.

To get the data I'm using simply:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['contentBox'].getData()
```

Example of data after submit in the DB:

```
<p>\n   Heloo<br />\n   How are you?</p>\n
<p>\n   Another Subject<br />\n My name is Luis</p>\n
```

All is fine, just want to cancel the `\n`. I don't wanna use REGEX or another PHP functions which will remove it.. I prefer solution via the config of CKEditor.

**EDIT ::**

**CKEditor is not the problem (look at `David Mulder` answer).**

Ajax code I created (probably the problem):

```
$('#edit').live('click', function() {
    if ($("#formValue").valid())
    {
        $('.simplebox').slideUp(200, function() {
            $('body').animate({scrollTop:140}, 350, function() {
                $('#loading-edit').slideDown(300, function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "../new_lesson_proccess/",
                        data: getDataToPost(),
                        success: function(data){

                            if (data.success == true)
                            {
                                $('#loading-edit').fadeOut(200, function() {
                                    $('.name_news_success').html($('input[name=name]').val());
                                    $('#successfull-edit').fadeIn(200);
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
})

function getDataToPost()
{
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['valuecontent'].getData();

    return {
        id: $('input[name=news_id]').val(),
        tags : $('#tags').textext()[0].tags()._formData,
        name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
        content: value
    }
}
```

What could be wrong here?

**EDIT 2 ::**

I'm using `CodeIgniter` framework.

*Part of the controller:*

```
public function new_lesson_proccess()
    {
        // # POST to Array
        $data = array(
            'content' => $this->input->post('content', FALSE)
        );

        $dataExport = array(
            'success' => $this->lessons_model->news_lesson($data)
        );

        echo json_encode($dataExport);
    }
```

*Part of the model `lessons_model`:*

```
function new_lesson($data)
    {
        $dataInsert = array(
            'content' => mysql_real_escape_string($data['content'])
        );

        if ($this->db->affected_rows($this->db->insert('web_lessons', $dataInsert)) == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Encoding: `UTF-8`

The field `content` in the database is defined as `TEXT`

I removed some code of validation & etc because it's not important.

Comment: Can you show the part where you process and store the data in the db?  character 13 is simply \n but if they appear as literal \n in the db. could be the way you process the data has the issue.

Comment: Added. I don't see any problem with the code but maybe I'm missing something..

Comment: does the validation code change $data['content']?  also if magic_quotes is on, I wonder it might lead to \n character in combination with mysql_real_escape_string. not sure about this. but is it ON?

Comment: I've cleaned up your AJAX code using recommendations by [**JSLint**](http://jsfiddle.net/WLznE/). If that helps let me know. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
   {
      ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
         {
            indent : false,
            breakBeforeOpen : true,
            breakAfterOpen : false,
            breakBeforeClose : false,
            breakAfterClose : true
         });
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this might be your solution:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/3260

Comment: The problem wasn't solved there. He said that he used `nl2br()` when fetches data. I just want to remove the '\n' before insert to the DB. I have already `<br />` or `<p>` in the code.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit of a long shot, but I think that this could quite likely be not a setting of ckEditor (as I used ckEditor extensively in the past, and encountered no such problem), but rather a feature (changing `character 10` and `character 13` to the `\n` notation) of either the ajax library you're using or the database library. Either way, log and inspect at which point `chr(13)` is replaced by the `\n` in the first place and if it's in the ajax library then it only makes sense to parse it back in your php code and if it's in your database script then you would need to change it somewhere inside of there (I wouldn't be too suprised, as I know of people who prefer having no 'hidden' characters in their database like line breaks). Of course this answer only stands if you're trying to get the line breaks to be in the valid format, if you simply don't care about the linebreaks `Lee Taylor` answer would be the place to go.

Comment: First of all thank you, after some tests the problem isn't the CKEditor as you said. I think it's something with the Ajax (I'm using jQuery to this) because the action is working well if I don't use ajax.
Anyway, the ajax code is very simple (I edited my main post and posted it there).. I don't see any problem with the code, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: In that case you should simply parse it back on the backend side. Are you btw maybe using a GET rather than a POST request, because in a GET request a linebreak character is impossible for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this ckeditor output formatters: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

Also this answer may help: [Removing unwanted newline characters when adding <p> in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547090/removing-unwanted-newline-characters-when-adding-p-in-ckeditor)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I faced the same problem and just wanted to share my solution.

Im using jquery's ajax method, to post the data to my php script, and the content breaklines is changed to \n.

Here is my (workaround) solution, I do this in the php script, before parsing the data to the database:

```
if (strpos($content,'\n') !== false) {
    $content = str_replace('\n', chr(13), $content);
}
```